# need to change a color for each icon individually

Tags: javascript

```js
if i have export const newColor = {
  color: "#00FF00",
  color2: "#D52027",
}; and const changeColor = () => {
    setColor(newColor.color2);
  }; how should i type {Object.keys(config).map((icon, index, id) => {
            for (id = 0; id > id.length; id++)
              return (
                <StyledIconMedia
                  // onClick={handleClick}
                  onClick={changeColor}
                  backgroundColor={color}
                  key={index}
                  icon={icon}
                  size={30}
                  color={"white"}
                />
              );
```

here I have the const with some colours and need to use one of them to change each icon colour individually on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

HTML

```
<div>
    <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 2</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 3</button>
    <button class="btn">Button 4</button>
</div>
```

and JS is

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
var colors = ['#ff0000', '#0066ff', '#009900', '#ffff66'];

for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length));
        this.style.backgroundColor = colors[pos];
    });
}
```